# How can I evaluate the sum $\sum_{a+b=1;\ a,b \in \mathbb F_p} \left(\frac{a}{p}\right) \chi(b)$ where $\chi$ is a multiplicative character of $\mathbb F_p^{*}$ of order three?

Tags: nt.number-theory

How can I evaluate the sum $$\sum_{a+b=1 ;\ a,b \in \mathbb F_p}\left(\frac{a}{p}\right) \chi(b)$$
where $\chi$ is a multiplicative character of $\mathbb F_p^{*}$ of order three?

Thanks!

Comment: Your title is slightly repetitive :)

Comment: I've made the title repetitive with the question in a hopefully more useful way.

Comment: Maybe some context of where this sum comes from would help. I didn't notice any immediately obvious patterns when I ran this in SAGE, although you seem to get -1 if and only if p is a cuban prime.

Comment: What makes you think there is a nice expression for it?

Comment: It comes from counting points on the e.c. $E:y^2+x^3=1$. One can show (by simple calculations) that if $p=3m+1$ then the number of points is exactly $1+p+J+\overline{J}$, where $J$ is the sum.

In fact, I need to show that $J \in \mathbb Z[\zeta]$ with $\zeta$ a cuberoot of unit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I've understood the question correctly, this is just a Jacobi sum. The question only seems to make sense for $p$ a prime congruent to 1 mod 3. In this case, the order 3 character and the quadratic character are distinct, and not inverses of each other either, so the absolute value of the Jacobi sum is going to be $\sqrt{p}$ (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_sum)). It's also clearly an algebraic integer, so it is one of the factors of $p$ in the factorization of $p$ into two primes in $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ with $\omega$ a cube root of unity. Now one gets into the usual thorny questions about signs, but the bottom line is that there may be a relatively simple way of expressing the sum in terms of $A$ and $B$ once you have written $p=A^2+AB+B^2$, the main problem with making this precise is that $A$ and $B$ are not unique, and you'll have to get things right mod 3 before you know exactly which way is up.

Comment: The old title was "Jacobi sum Jacobi sum", perhaps I should have edited the title differently.

Comment: I am Jacobi! No, *I* am Jacobi! ...

Comment: Ohh thank you very much! I just have anothe rquestion..

Do you know an easy way to show that $J \overline J$ in $p$?

Comment: Why not use the purely elementary argument in e.g. Washington's Cyclotomic Fields to write the Jacobi sum as a ratio of Gauss sums, and then prove the analogous result for the Gauss sums in a purely elementary way, and then write it all down and see how much cancels?